# Accessing Hive using JdbcIO in apache beam throws HivePreparedStatement.getMetaData, Method not supported

Tags: jdbc, hive, apache-beam

I'm trying to access hive table using beam JDBCIO. But below exception has thrown while connecting to hive, Any help from the beam geeks would be really helpful.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method not supported
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.getMetaData (HivePreparedStatement.java:201)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.getMetaData (DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:151)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.getMetaData (DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:151)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteVoid.getFilteredFields (JdbcIO.java:2114)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteVoid.expand (JdbcIO.java:2064)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Write.expand (JdbcIO.java:1698)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Write.expand (JdbcIO.java:1596)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal (Pipeline.java:548)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform (Pipeline.java:482)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply (PCollection.java:360)
```

Below code snippet is trying to access hive :

```
p.apply(JdbcIO.<Row>read()
        .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
                .create("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "jdbc:hive2://<ip>/mydb")
                .withUsername("username").withPassword("password"))
        .withQuery("select * from test_hive")
        .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<Row>() {
            @Override
            public Row mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception
```

POM Dependecies has set hive-jdbc:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```